# Set the value in a link function of a directive to AngularJs model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive as below.

#### JavaScript

```
app.directive('myDirectve',function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        //Some code
        var computedModelValue = 100;
        //Some code
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };
});
```

### HTML

```
<input ng-model="computedValue" disabled="disabled" />
<my-Directve></my-Directve>
{{computedValue}}
```

Now I want to bind the value `computedModelValue` in the `link` function to `computedValue` (Model) in the input tag.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: The link function is normally used for manipulating the UI (with things like jQuery). Generally speaking, you should be using it for computation. Is there a reason why this model value is being computed here and not in a controller?

Comment: @JamesConsidine You are right.I have implemented a Jquery widget inside the link function and that widget return this computed value.I want to bind that value to the $scope of the Angular controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the input filed was changing by Jquery widget in the 'link' function and after changing it doesn't trigger any event, to notify angularJS even though it's binded.So I triggered an event once changed the value of the text field after changing the value.

```
        var myModel = $('#id');
        myModel.val(val);
        myModel.trigger('input');
```